# How to productively develop system apps on Android Marshmallow platform?

Tags: android-source

I am working on developing Android privileged system apps with an `eng` build of the platform...

In Lollipop I was able to set `LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false` then use `mm` to build my APKs, do `adb remount` and `adb push` the APK to the system partition. The system would detect the changes and rebuild the dex and my productivity was high. If the app was `persistent` I just needed to additionally kill the process.

Now I am running into all kinds of problems with this process while developing on Marshmallow. Pushing the APK and attempting to run gives:

> 02-01 20:58:26.302 E/dex2oat ( 3045): Failed to create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@priv-app@XYZ@XYZ.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied

SELinux trouble:

> [ 1614.216323] type=1400 audit(686361.299:48): avc: denied { write }
>   for pid=2640 comm="oid.XYZ" name="arm64" dev="dm-0" ino=360453
>   scontext=u:r:system_app:s0
>   tcontext=u:object_r:dalvikcache_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

I have tried all kinds of hacks to get around this...

Sure I could rebuild the entire system img and flash it but that kills productivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out a much simpler alternative to modifying SELinux and app_main.cpp. Following these steps allows me to update my system apps quickly:

1. Build the app with `LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false` so the dex file remains in the APK
2. `adb remount` at least once
3. `adb rm -rf /system/priv-app/XYZ/oat`
4. `adb push $OUT/system/priv-app/XYZ/XYZ.apk /system/priv-app/XYZ/`

Comment: Note that on Nougat there is no `oat` directory so you can skip that step and develop just like Lollipop.

Comment: One problem with the above solution is that changes to `AndroidManifest.xml` do not take effect unless the OS is restarted with `adb shell stop` and `adb shell start`, even on Nougat. Would love to know of a workaround that doesn't require kicking the whole OS.